# How can I pass a value through to an SSRS report even when it returns no records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a procedure that calculates a date range based on some inputs, and then selects a group of records based on that date range. My SSRS report based on this procedure works great, unless there are no records to return...and then it no longer displays that calculated date range. This looks like the report failed. I can tell the user that there are no records available, but if they don't understand all the parameters well enough, they may not know why that is. For example, one option is to just select all records that shipped during the last week of the month, not including anything that spilled over into the next month. So in December of 2015, this meant starting with Sunday, December 27th and ending with Thursday, December 31st. They may be expecting that a record from January 1st would be included in the week, and not understand why it didn't show up. But if I can get it to display the date range, it might make more sense.

Comment: Why don't you calculate the data range from SSRS instead of take it from the data returned by the procedure?

Comment: I considered this, but it's a pretty complicated query...takes up most of my procedure. Plus, to be honest, I'm really not good enough with SSRS...and I'm barely adequate in T-SQL.

Comment: I thought for a minute that I had figured it out...I did something that was so simple and obvious that it's ridiculous that I hadn't thought of it before, which was to simply add a second SELECT statement in my procedure. When I run the query in SQL, it still comes back blank, but then it displays the date range on a separate line. But when I run the SSRS report, it still doesn't return them. I even added them in a separate dataset. I think I probably don't really understand how SSRS works well enough to know why it's doing this.

Comment: Using T-SQL you can validate if your query is not returning records, if so you can use another select statement to calculate the date range.

Comment: Brilliant! You have saved me. I was afraid I was going to have to create two separate procedures and call them both. The code I used is IF EXISTS and then the same WHERE statement I was using to check the records.